# Checkout Process Redirect to Shopping Cart is empty

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, redirect, shopping-cart

My checkout page not work properly. I have recently installed SSL and memcache.
When click on addtocart its work fine. but when click on process checkout its redirect to Shopping Cart is empty. I dont know what is problem. below my backend setting.

[image]

Comment: When enabling `display_errors = 1` at .user.ini you got to know the error reason.then you can be able tosolve this

Comment: try this : https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/wired-issue-shopping-cart-is-empty-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to this question, as it hasn't been answered correctly yet. 
You can fix this issue by following these steps:

1. Go to **Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web**.
2. Go to **Secure** settings. Change the **Base URL** to **HTTPS://**.
3. Choose **Yes** for **Use Secure URL for frontend** option.
4. Click on **Save**.

You will find that the issue has been fixed. You can find more information about these steps [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-solve-the-10-most-common-magento-ssl-issues/).